# Is there any open source AI engine?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am searching for an open source AI engine implemented in C/C++, ActionScript or Java with no success. Do you know any open source implementation?

Update: Thanks for answers! I had no idea how vast the AI field is. I am working on a sample application. I want to add intelligent behavior over a physics engine. I need some sort ai engine designed for games.

Comment: AI is a wast domain of computer science. Which part of it are you interested in?

Comment: Agreed. Wery wery wast. :-)

Comment: http://www.tensorflow.org/ from google is now opensource

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"AI engine" can mean an awful lot of different things. What kind of "AI" are you looking for?

Here is [a list of some machine learning software](http://www.dmoztools.net/Computers/Artificial_Intelligence/Machine_Learning/Software/). Many of them are open source (the linked page shows the licenses).

Comment: I look over the following project on sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/robocode/ , http://sourceforge.net/projects/markiv/ , http://sourceforge.net/projects/uvsim/ , http://sourceforge.net/projects/simspark/ . Thanks for answering.

Comment: link not available.. site closed now

Comment: @RanjithKumar thanks. Link updated.

Answer (score 13):

I assume you are looking for [Game AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_artificial_intelligence) and not [Artificial Intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) in general.

As far as I know, there is no such thing as AI engine. You have to be more specific. Do you need pathfinding? Do you need FSM? Goal-Oriented?

Other engines include RTS specific engines (OpenRTS is an open source one), first person shooters (new FPS games have their own API such as F.E.A.R.).

The most general purpose engine I can think of is [Alive!](http://alive.sourceforge.net/) the AI sandbox designed by [AIGameDev.com](https://aigamedev.com/)

Comment: I like Alive! Nice project. Has many of the features I need.

Answer (score 8):

Artificial intelligence is a pretty big field.  I'm not sure that there's one "engine" that encompasses all of AI.  Do you mean a Rete rules engine?  Try Drools.  Do you mean a neural network approach?  Support vector machines?  Active or passive learning?  There's no one approach.

I really like what I see in "Programming Collective Intelligence".  A nice variety of techniques, written in Python.

Answer (score 6):

You should specify an AI category, anyway this is my favorite link: [AI on the Web](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/ai.html).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ekione.com/

This would be your best bet I think....it's an engine for AI and emotional intelligence for games and it is implemented in C++ to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in path finding and spatial reasoning (which is often what is called ai in the games domain) check out recast and detour: http://code.google.com/p/recastnavigation/

Answer (score 1):

A very interesting presentation on the AI for games can be found [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/ijcaiigames/):

> The tutorial will give an introduction
>   to the area of applying AI techniques,
>   such as learning, search and planning,
>   to video games. It will focus on past
>   and recent applications, open problems
>   and promising avenues for future
>   research, and on resources available
>   to people who would like to work in
>   this space.

Other than a good coverage of the theory you'll find links to a number of games (some open source like NERO & TORCS) that implement the ideas discussed.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you are looking for, but the Google Prediction API is pretty cool: http://code.google.com/apis/predict/

Check it out.  Lots of good AI there in the context of data mining.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an action planner, you could use my open sourced GPGOAP which is a goal-oriented-action-planner with zero dependencies, written in C. https://github.com/stolk/GPGOAP

Answer (score 0):

please use the link below to list out AI project on github. Projects are in almost every language. Hopefully you will find it helpful.
[https://github.com/search?o=desc&p=10&q=artificial+intelligence&ref=searchresults&s=stars&type=Repositories](https://github.com/search?o=desc&p=10&q=artificial%20intelligence&ref=searchresults&s=stars&type=Repositories)

Answer (score 0):

As an AI engine in general, you can try OpenCog: http://opencog.org/

As a game AI engine e.g. Stockfish is specific for chess: http://stockfishchess.org/

Answer (score 0):

For text processing, the Apache OpenNLP, UIMA and related projects can be fun.  They are Java based, and the UIMA has associated Eclipse tooling that makes it somewhat easier to use.